# Loosing context on map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, closures

Im trying to add new columns to my component state array. But I get undefined value. I can't understand how to bind this

```
const data = SberData;

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        columns: [
            {Header: 'value1'},
            {Header: 'value2'}
        ]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    data.map((element) => {
            return this.setState(state => ({
                        columns: [...state.columns, {Header: element.value}]
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```

and what I get:

```
0: {Header: "value1"}
1: {Header: "value2"}
2: {Header: undefined}
3: {Header: undefined}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but [Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) does not have `map()` method.. Could you give more context on what are you trying to do?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Could you show us SberData ? Also, you should replace map by `forEach` since you don't care about what the `map` returns, and you don't need to return this.setState

Comment: OK, thanks, and now what's in this `data` constant? Could you print it out? Maybe elements of the array (I assume it's an array) don't have `value` property? Also, it may be better to prepare required data and then call `setState()` just one time.

Comment: You should not use `map` if you don't do anything with the result. Use a plain `for of` loop instead.

Comment: Thank you guys! ur right, they doesn't gave value property

Comment: Glad you solved it :) But still, consider one of the advises above - either use `.map()` to prepare the data and call `setState()` once or use `.forEach()` or `for of` loop. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out in the comments that elements just didn't have `value` property, but still, I suggest improving the code a bit, prepare the data and then call `setState()` once, for example:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const newColumns = data.map(element => ({Header: element.value}));
  this.setState(state => ({
    columns: [...state.columns, newColumns]
  });
}
```